# undefined method ` ' for #<EmailMessagesController:0xad910d4>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gmail-api

I am getting

> ```
> undefined method ` ' for #<EmailMessagesController:0xad910d4>
> ```

when on this line

```
array = header.reject { |hash| hash.name != 'From' }
```

I am trying to get from param from gmail message array header part.

Although this code work without error if I place this code in view file, but in controller I am getting undefined method error.

```
    result = service.get_user_message('me',msg.id)
    header = result.payload.headers 
    array = header.reject { |hash| hash.name != 'From' }
    array.first.value
```

Comment: what does header look like?

Comment: @neo same code works fine in view (html.erb) file, but in controller or helper it thrown error

Comment: header.reject, not sure where you're setting `header` variable and what it is? is it an Array or a Hash?

Comment: it is an array @neo

Comment: Please include more of the stacktrace.

Comment: Errors like this one can indicate that you have a "hard space"/"non-breaking space" (Opt+space on a Mac) where you expected to have a regular space. Though if the code works when copied from controller to view, I guess this is unlikely.

Comment: @HenrikN thanks for comment, I just did this other way, also code works in view but not in controller/helper and model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to find another way to fetch desired header and rails is not throwing error. It is working fine. I think rail reject has some problem with data parse

```
hash = Hash.new
result.payload.headers.each do |hedr|
hash[hedr.name] = hedr.value            
end
from = hash['From']
```